# How to create pair-wise data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` with sample data from multiple `sites` and `years`. I would like to create a new "pairwise" `data.frame` that takes creates three columns, `Site_Year`, `Value_2008`, `Value_Year`, where `Value_Year` is the value for any other year in the dataset. For example, in my sample dataset the site "Anjan" is visited in 2008, 2009, 2010. The new `data.frame` to have two records for this `site`:

```
Site_Year Value_2008 Value_Year
Anjan.2009 0.11 0.96
Anjan.2010 0.11 -0.25
```

If there is a `site` that was sampled before 2008 the results would look like:

```
Site_Year Value_2008 Value_Year
Ljungdalen.2005 0.09 -0.40
Ljungdalen.2009 0.09 0.32
Ljungdalen.2011 0.09 -0.00
```

Ultimately, I am going to plot these results so that I can look at changes in these (mean) values between years and test them to see if they are significantly different.

**Sample data:**

```
WW_Site_Year_Data <- structure(list(Site_Year = c("Anjan.2008", "Anjan.2009", "Anjan.2010",
"Fittjebodarna.2008", "Fittjebodarna.2009", "Flatruet.2008",
"Flatruet.2009", "Flatruet.2010", "Flatruet.2011", "Fotingen.2008",
"Fotingen.2009", "Gestvallen.2008", "Gestvallen.2009", "Glen.2008",
"Glen.2009", "Glen.2010", "Gräftåvallen.2008", "Gräftåvallen.2009",
"Hallbodarna.2008", "Hallbodarna.2009", "Ljungdalen.2005", "Ljungdalen.2008",
"Ljungdalen.2009", "Ljungdalen.2011", "Ljungris.2008", "Ljungris.2009",
"Ljungris.2010", "Mårdsund.2008", "Mårdsund.2009", "Mårdsund.2010",
"Öster_Galåbodarna.2008", "Öster_Galåbodarna.2009", "Ramundberget.2008",
"Ramundberget.2009", "Rätan.2008", "Rätan.2009", "Rätan.2010",
"Särvfjället.2008", "Särvfjället.2009", "Storulvån.2008", "Storulvån.2009",
"Storulvån.2010", "Tångböle.2005", "Tångböle.2008", "Tångböle.2009",
"Tossåsen.2008", "Tossåsen.2009", "Vålådalen.2008", "Vålådalen.2009",
"Vålådalen.2010", "Vemdalsskalet.2002", "Vemdalsskalet.2008",
"Vemdalsskalet.2009"), Site_Name = c("Anjan", "Anjan", "Anjan",
"Fittjebodarna", "Fittjebodarna", "Flatruet", "Flatruet", "Flatruet",
"Flatruet", "Fotingen", "Fotingen", "Gestvallen", "Gestvallen",
"Glen", "Glen", "Glen", "Gräftåvallen", "Gräftåvallen", "Hallbodarna",
"Hallbodarna", "Ljungdalen", "Ljungdalen", "Ljungdalen", "Ljungdalen",
"Ljungris", "Ljungris", "Ljungris", "Mårdsund", "Mårdsund", "Mårdsund",
"Öster_Galåbodarna", "Öster_Galåbodarna", "Ramundberget", "Ramundberget",
"Rätan", "Rätan", "Rätan", "Särvfjället", "Särvfjället", "Storulvån",
"Storulvån", "Storulvån", "Tångböle", "Tångböle", "Tångböle",
"Tossåsen", "Tossåsen", "Vålådalen", "Vålådalen", "Vålådalen",
"Vemdalsskalet", "Vemdalsskalet", "Vemdalsskalet"), Year = c("2008",
"2009", "2010", "2008", "2009", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011",
"2008", "2009", "2008", "2009", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2008",
"2009", "2008", "2009", "2005", "2008", "2009", "2011", "2008",
"2009", "2010", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2008", "2009", "2008",
"2009", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2008", "2009", "2008", "2009",
"2010", "2005", "2008", "2009", "2008", "2009", "2008", "2009",
"2010", "2002", "2008", "2009"), Value = c(0.112816109860291,
0.960290707474735, -0.257326331130005, 0.216427465038733, 0.956767099330118,
0.0526510364211729, 0.588996350906268, -0.465285757216318, -0.0437472490447301,
0.535560060909972, 0.389645985829418, 0.89391173396597, 0.240894790643034,
0.469695915206932, 0.251017199176266, -0.208323019946377, 0.0849050148677196,
0.184296870311739, -0.107309010266098, 0.36349491505071, -0.396608387512831,
0.0931374765423872, 0.32514153209616, -0.00466699456138238, 0.336789804880864,
0.806764888899387, -0.13955949253251, 0.108716189818012, 0.0978498660969545,
-0.160915801270199, 0.623151244760041, 0.713080174849265, -0.279733235253308,
0.427277452192635, 0.296839613563375, 0.659552054627706, 0.356154916318252,
0.659219370597927, 0.825734934055685, 0.183577169158829, 1.31979282562961,
0.0574714990570691, -0.517636804796056, 0.478950613513035, 0.504156229919797,
0.915335741962761, 1.11129338570452, 0.205145037964442, 0.829430613619136,
-0.187573312149385, -0.646545555669656, -0.034670665219269, 1.68156971430668
)), .Names = c("Site_Year", "Site_Name", "Year", "Value"), row.names = c(1L,
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L,
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L,
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L,
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What do you want for `Value_2008` for a site like Tänndalen which has no entry for 2008?

Comment: I will just remove it from the dataset. I meant to do that already, I apologize.

Comment: Edited the answer to handle that case: no need for the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very useful package in this situation is `plyr`:

```
ddply(WW_Site_Year_Data, .(Site_Name), transform,
      Value_2008 = if (2008 %in% Year) Value[Year==2008] else NA)
```

If records with no Value for 2008 are excluded from the data frame you could use

```
ddply(WW_Site_Year_Data, .(Site_Name), transform,
      Value_2008 = Value[Year==2008])
```

It you want to use base R, it's uglier:

```
unsplit(lapply(split(WW_Site_Year_Data, WW_Site_Year_Data$Site_Name),
        transform, Value_2008 = if (2008 %in% Year) Value[Year==2008] else NA),
        WW_Site_Year_Data$Site_Name)
```

Comment: works nice, it would be nice to know how to do it in the base package though!

Comment: I've added the base R version: split, apply, combine. The plyr package is built on the idea of combining these three common steps in a single function.